# i am having this issue when i am trying to check npm version in cmd

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
`node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message)`
```

Error: Cannot find module 'yallist'

Comment: what command are you trying to enter in cmd? is NodeJS installed in your machine?
"npm --version" , this command should give you back your current npm version

Comment: Since people won't be able to see your screen, so make sure that you edit the question to include more details on your computer setup, Node.js environment setup and other key information. Otherwise, a low quality question won't get answers.

Comment: I am just entering npm -v